# What does it mean if a method has a type of return an interface?

Tags: c#

When I have a method like this:

```
public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
{
foreach (string str in array)
yield return str
}
```

A method  "int" returns an int.

But A method that returns an interface what does it mean?

Comment: [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) is used for enumerators (hence the return type of `IEnumerator<String>`), but in general the function would be returning an object that implements the specified interface.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I

Comment: "str" then implements the interface now?

Comment: It means that the method can return any type that implements said interface.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx

Comment: After that method, it would be just this code?


public interface IEnumerator<T>

{

string str {get; set;}

}

Answer (score 4):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a bit of a special type when it comes to the `yield` keyword. Basically it means the return type of the method is a "Enumerable", meaning that it is some kind of list of items (`string` in this case).

This method doesn't have anything to do with it being an interface, the magic lies in the `yield` keyword.

[More info on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's not returning an interface, but it's returning an instance of an object that uses that interface. This is a subject known as [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Polymorphism allows you to return different implementations of classes that derive from a base type or interface. In your code, you could return an implementation of a MyCollectionType or a MyListType (both being custom collection types you could create that implement that interface) since they both implement the `IEnumerator` interface.

Answer (score -1):

`Interfaces` are just generic contracts that say whatever actual type returned will be able to do x, y, and z.

Consider the following:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string First { get; set; }
    string Last { get; set; }
}
```

You can then have different types of implementations (`Contact`, `Employee`) but they will all have a `First` and `Last` property that you can call.

```
public interface Contact : IPerson
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    // Maybe other methods too
}


public interface Employee : IPerson
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    // Maybe other methods too
}
```

Say you have the following method:

```
public IPerson GetPerson()
{
    var contact = new Contact();
    var employee = new Employee();

    // You can return either of these objects and the code that call it will be able to call the `First` and `Last` parameters.
}
```

With your example `IEnumerable<T>` you have something that can be enumerated over for things like `for (var item in list)`.